# boxplot using plotly.express package not showing in the knitted pdf file. How can I rectify?

Tags: python, boxplot, plotly-python, export-to-pdf

I am a student and I am using `plotly.express` package to plot a `boxplot` in a `.ipynb` file. The reason I chose that package is because it shows an interactive figure describing the median, lower and upper quantile etc. But unfortunately, after knitting the file to pdf, the image is not being shown. Not sure what is the reason behind this and how can I rectify the same

I have installed `plotly` package and used the necessary code which is shown below. I tried the same on jupyter notebook, visual studio and google collab (print option) but the result is the same.

```
#importing 'plotly.express' to create an interactive box plot
import plotly.express as px

#creating a boxplot of 'Sales' data to visualize the outliers
boxPlot_sales = px.box(salesData['sales'])

boxPlot_sales.update_layout(title_text="Box Plot of Sales data")

boxPlot_sales.show()
```

[boxplot in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kskF.jpg)
[boxplot in knitted pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukYz9.jpg)

Comment: Refer to:[https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/)